# HTML Textarea auto-width with custom font returns wrong scrollWidth initially

Tags: javascript, html, css

**EDIT:** Please refer to bottom of post with a workaround I found which works in Chrome but not in Safari/Firefox.

I have a textarea which I want the width & height to grow/shrink as user types in it. While most solutions on stack overflow are regarding height auto-grow, I have used the similar technique to get width auto-grow too.

This works well with the default sans-serif font. But if I use a Google font, then the `scrollWidth` being reported `onload` is not based on the custom font, it's being reported using the default font and therefore wrong. It seems like the `onload` method gets called before custom fonts have been applied.

I have implemented a simple test case for this demo. Note that the JSFiddle seems to only show the issue first time sometimes - it seems to cache the font afterwards and no longer shows the issue. But if I use chrome and open the developer tools and disable cache in the Network tab, then it continues to show the issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/fpr0dns6/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Poppins';
            src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/poppins/v15/pxiEyp8kv8JHgFVrJJfecnFHGPc.woff2);
        }

        textarea {
            font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
            font-size: 25px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            background: aquamarine;
            border: none;
            resize: none;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        onload = function () {
            document.body.innerHTML = `<textarea id="mytext" rows="1" cols="1" placeholder="Something Long String" onfocus="auto_grow(this)" onclick="auto_grow(this)" oninput="auto_grow(this)"></textarea>`
            auto_grow(document.getElementById('mytext'))
        }

        function auto_grow(element) {
            console.log(getComputedStyle(element).fontFamily)
            element.style.width = "auto";
            element.style.width = (element.scrollWidth) + "px";
            element.style.height = "auto";
            console.log(element.scrollHeight + ", " + element.scrollWidth)
            element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight) + "px";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the result:

[image]

For troubleshooting purposes, I have added `onfocus` and `onclick` listeners to the textarea. So if the user focuses on the textarea after load, it corrects itself.

I am not sure how to solve this. Is there a way for `onload` to wait for custom font to apply?

Another thing I noticed in Firefox with an even worse behavior. Even after click/focus, the textarea doesn't show the correct width:

[image]

I am aware of the `setTimeout` way to delay it for 300ms before calling my function but this seems like a hack which will fail sometimes.

**EDIT:**

I found a workaround using `document.fonts.onloadingdone` to call `auto_grow(document.getElementById('mytext'))` which works in Chrome. But it doesn't work on Safari or Firefox. Apparently it's an experimental feature:

https://caniuse.com/?search=onloadingdone

Any better solutions?

**EDIT 2:** I found this which I am testing now and will update this question with my findings:

https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader

**EDIT 3:** I just tested with `webfontloader` library above and it does seem to work well in Safari and Chrome. Firefox for some reason continues to report the wrong `scrollWidth` but I don't think that's related to this fonts issue.